# how to use Raycast NGUI in RTS Game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, isometric, ngui

I am working on the 2D Isometric RTS project.
It's like They are Billions or Starcraft.
But while working on the map-editor, RayCast faced an unbreakable problem with NGUI.
Although you must create the ground when you click the mouse, UICamera.hoveredObject will continue to return UIRoot

[Scenes returning UIRoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oUOs.png)

```
private void CreateTileOnMousePos()
{
    Debug.Log(UICamera.hoveredObject);
    if (UICamera.hoveredObject == null)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit;
        if (hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)))//, grid.unwalkableMask))
        {
            Node node = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(hit.point);
            Vector3Int pos = tilemaps[0].WorldToCell(node.worldPosition);// + tilemaps[0].tileAnchor);

            node.enviormentTile = EnviormentTile.Gress;
            tilemaps[0].SetTile(pos, tilePrefabs[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

If UIRoot's SetActive is off, of course it works.
Select another tile or save/load map information through UIButton.
I want to use these NGUI to implement the interface of real game
I don't know if the transition is stupid because it's my first time working on it.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do what I intended without turning off UIRoot SetActive

===========================================================================

I don't know how to use GraphicRayCast due to lack of skills, but first I solved it by that method.

```
if (UICamera.Raycast(Input.mousePosition) == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("UICamera.Raycast ture");
    }
    else
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit;

        if (hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)))//, grid.unwalkableMask))
        {
            Node node = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(hit.point);
            Vector3Int pos = tilemaps[0].WorldToCell(node.worldPosition);// + tilemaps[0].tileAnchor);

            node.enviormentTile = EnviormentTile.Gress;
            tilemaps[0].SetTile(pos, tilePrefabs[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you tried using a mask, why didn't that work?

Comment: The mask was inserted to use the A* algorithm related to unit movement.
I am using the main camera and the UI camera together.
Problem is, before using a layer mask,
UICamera.hoveredObject continues to return UIRoot even though BoxCollider is not present

Comment: It has a *GraphicRaycaster* on it though. You need to use a layer mask that excludes the UI layer, I suspect.

Comment: I tried that method, but I have a problem with creating tiles on the ground when I click the UI button to change the tiles or give special commands.

Comment: Ah, GraphicRaycaster has never tried.
I'll try it later.